# CopyFile error code 2

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, file-io

I have to create console application, which finds all .txt files in directory and makes copies of them to .copytxt format in the same directory. Program returns me error code 2 from CopyFile function. I really dont know where is the problem. I tried to use this reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365522(v=vs.85).aspx

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"


#define SOURCE_PATH _T(R"(C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\4.semester\PB173\Ukol1\text\)")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
WIN32_FIND_DATA findData;
HANDLE findHandle;
BOOL fFinished = FALSE;
TCHAR oldPath[MAX_PATH];
TCHAR newPath[MAX_PATH];
DWORD attrs;

_tcscpy_s(oldPath, _T("\\?\)"));
_tcscpy_s(oldPath, SOURCE_PATH);
_tcscat_s(oldPath, _T("*.txt"));
_tprintf(_T("%s\n"), oldPath);

findHandle = FindFirstFile(oldPath, &findData);
if (findHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    _tprintf(_T("The first file found is %s\n"), findData.cFileName);

    while (!fFinished)
    {
        _tcscpy_s(newPath, _T("\\?\)"));
        _tcscpy_s(newPath, SOURCE_PATH);
        TCHAR* pChar;
        TCHAR* savePtr;
        pChar = _tcstok_s(findData.cFileName, _T("."), &savePtr);
        _tcscat_s(newPath, pChar);
        _tcscat_s(newPath, _T(".copytxt"));
        _tprintf(_T("%s\n"), newPath);

        //StringCchPrintf(newPath, sizeof(newPath) / sizeof(newPath[0]), TEXT("%s\\%s"), oldPath, findData.cFileName);

        if (CopyFile(findData.cFileName, newPath, FALSE))
        {
            attrs = GetFileAttributes(findData.cFileName);
            if (attrs == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) break;
            SetFileAttributes(newPath, attrs);

            _tprintf(_T("File %s copied successfully.\n"), findData.cFileName);
        }
        else
        {
            _tprintf(_T("Could not copy file %s.\n"), findData.cFileName);
            _tprintf(_T("%d\n"), GetLastError());

            break;
        }


        if (!FindNextFile(findHandle, &findData))
        {
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
            {
                _tprintf(_T("All files *.txt were copied.\n"));
                fFinished = TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                _tprintf(_T("Could not find next file.\n"));
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    FindClose(findHandle);
}
else
{
    _tprintf(TEXT("FindFirstFile failed (%d)\n"), GetLastError());
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you see [this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), error `2` is `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

Comment: 2 is ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. (from WinError.h), what are the values of findData.cFileName and newPath?

Comment: IIRC, cFileName is only the filename.  If you don't prepend it with the source path, the copyfile will fail:(

Comment: ..in fact, I'll promote that to an answer:)

Comment: Why it works in the reference I linked up here?

Comment: It's not my job to debug Microsoft's bad code:)

Comment: MS example uses the 'current directory', not a fully-qualified path.  Yes, it's rubbish:)

Comment: Also, not sure if you explicitly need to avoid trying to copy folders, including '.' and '..' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to strcat the cFileName to the end of the the source path before attempting the copyfile, else the file will not be found.

From MSDN:

> The cFileName field in this structure will not include a path, even if
>   a path was used in the call to FindFirstFile/FindNextFile. So if you
>   call FindFirstFile("C:\Windows\System32*", &finddata), finddata may
>   contain e.g. "drivers" or "cmd.exe" but not
>   "C:\Windows\System32\drivers" or "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe".

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape `\` as `\\` when you want to use an actual `\` character in literals.

You are also putting parenthesis characters inside your literal values.  You need to remove them.

Change

```
#define SOURCE_PATH _T(R"(C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\4.semester\PB173\Ukol1\text\)")
```

To

```
#define SOURCE_PATH _T("C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Documents\\4.semester\\PB173\\Ukol1\\text\\")
```

And

```
_T("\\?\)")
```

To

```
_T("\\\\?\\")
```